# changing text with help of Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I want change some text with help of Perl. I want find string "#blah bla blah" - uncommented it and added strings "abс hhhh", "dddd ccccc" after this string. How i can do it with help of /m, /s, or.. ?

Comment: [perldoc perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should uncomment and add `$suffix` to the end:

```
my $suffix = 'abс hhhh dddd ccccc';
$string =~ s{#(blah bla blah)}{$1 $suffix}g;
```

More information is at [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [perldoc perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict; use warnings;

while (<>) {
     s/^#(blah bla blah)/$1 abс hhhh dddd ccccc/;
}
```

Comment: I also think that the `if` is not necessary. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text you have is in the variable `$text`:

```
$text =~ s/(#blah bla blah)/$1 abс hhhh dddd ccccc/g;
```

Comment: Is that what the OP wants? I just understood that the string he's looking for is not commented on the actual text, but it's not really clear because of the syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pi -e 's/^#blah bla blah/blah bla blah abс hhhh dddd ccccc/g' your_file
```